Can we (almost always) walk from one Gaussian non-prime to another?
This is a plot of the Gaussian primes. They get sparser as you move further from $0$, so it looks like if you start on one of the white squares you could travel to any other white square (almost) without intersecting a black square (Gaussian integer). You cannot move diagonally. This seems like one of those obvious facts where one nevertheless has no clue where to start with a proof*, as well as being, I think, a pretty natural question about a pretty diagram. So I would really like to see how a question like this can even be approached.

How to make this question rigorous? I'm not entirely sure. One approach that would seem satisfying enough is to prove that there are no loops of Gaussian primes enclosing $0$, other than the ones we can see on the diagram. This doesn't rule out other structures that would make the Gaussian non-primes less connected than they appear, like an infinitely long (obviously not straight) line of primes, but it seems interesting enough. I'm interested in other results about other ways of operationalising the problem too, though.

*The only approach I can come up with is to use the asymptotic density of the Gaussian integers to show there aren't enough to form a loop around $0$ once you go far enough out, however this doesn't form a nearly tight enough bound. The number of Gaussian integers with norm $N(x+iy)=x^2+y^2$ between $\underline{r}$ and $\bar{r}$ is approximately $$\int_{\underline{r}}^{\bar{r}} \frac{x}{\ln x}dx$$
which grows faster than $O(\bar{r}-\underline{r})$, so is plenty to make a loop around $0$ in the annulus $\underline{r}^2<N(z)<\bar{r}^2$.

This is sort of the opposite of the Gaussian moat problem but maybe some of the ideas in that literature will be relevant: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Stroll-Through-the-Gaussian-Primes-Gethner-Wagon/7b7eb90bdbc4b37822ff92875870d0fa4d4fcc2a

This is just an idea on the 'how to make this question rigorous?' part. I don't have an answer to the actual very interesting question.
Define two Gaussian integers $x,y$ as connected if $|x-y|=1$ as complex numbers. For any subset of the Gaussian integers this generates an equivalence relation and the equivalence classes are the connected components of the subset.
One can now formulate multiple conjectures on the specific subset that consists of the Gaussian non-primes (in order of increasing strength):

there is only one infinite connected component
the density of the infinite component is equal to 1
there are only finitely many connected components in total

Intuitively I'm pretty sure that the first two are true but I'm not sure about the third one. A related question would be whether there are infinitely many Gaussian non-primes $z$ such that $z \pm 1$ and $z\pm i$ are Gaussian primes.

The third one is almost certainly false. It is conjectured that infinitly "diamonds" exist. A diamond consists of 4 gaussian primes that surround a composite.
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-10/issue-2/The-Gaussian-Zoo/em/999188629.full

@MichaelStocker Nice find, so after a quick glance through the paper it seems there is strong numerical evidence that infinitely many diamonds exist (which I referred to in my last sentence) and there also seem to be infinitely many of the larger structures they consider, some of which have a connected component of Gaussian non-primes inside them.
